# Writing drivers & stuff: sources for learning

Tags: hardware, drivers, programming

Are there good sources for learning how to write drivers for webcams, electronic devices and stuff for Linux? Besides reading the source code :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out some of the Questions on Stackoverflow.com (site based on the same engine as this one). Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux+driver) to linux driver tags.

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629129/are-there-recommended-tutorials-for-writing-drivers-for-gnu-linux) seems to have some links to some tutorials that may help you.